# Sending files through ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, file-transfer

I need to send files to a server using ssh. I have never used ssh so this is frustrating to me. I am running Windows and the server is running Ubuntu.

I connected to the server using ssh2 IP, and then logging with an account I have. Now, I would like to send my files to a folder in the server, so, I moved to the folder and I used this command:

```
scp test.txt user_name@host_direction server_folder_destination
```

It always return that it can't do 'stat' over test.txt, the file doesn't exist, and so.

I'm assuming ssh2 can't see the file in my computer root (C:), so I tried to specify more and added: C:\test.txt, but appear the same error. I don't know what is happening.

Any hints please?

Comment: "It always returns some kind of error, and so." Be *specific* - can you, possibly, copy and paste *both* the invocation, *and* the error. (If you're on Windows, perhaps try the WinSCP client? It's free and it has a quite useful GUI; I found it much easier to use than the command-line tools available for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> scp test.txt user_name@host_direction server_folder_destination
> ```

That isn't the right syntax. You need to do something like this:

```
scp test.txt user_name@host_direction:server_folder_destination
```

Note the `:` -- that tells scp you want to copy the local file 'test.txt' to host `host_direction`, connecting with user `user_name`, and store it in `server_folder_destination` (which will default to being relative to the remote user's home dir). See the [scp(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1) man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` is for running commands remotely. Use `scp` (or `sftp`) to transfer files to or from a remote host.

```
# send text.txt from this machine to /destination/path on remotehost
scp test.txt user@remotehost:/destination/path

# get test.txt from /foo/bar on remote host and store it here as foo.txt
scp user@remotehost:/foo/bar/test.txt foo.txt
```

Comment: That is what I did. Did you read the problem?

Comment: You're using `ssh2` and not `scp` or `sftp` according to what you wrote above, and the path syntax doesn't match what I put here

Comment: Oh, that's right. I meant scp. I wrote bad here, but in the console was right. That's not the problem

Comment: Your path syntax is still wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is with the path of the windows file... I don't know how to put it.

Comment: If test.txt is on your windows machine, the first command I put there needs to be run _on your windows machine_, not on the remote host.

Comment: @Frion3L if test.txt is on the Windows machine, you probably need to download pscp.exe from the [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) distribution to make this work. either that or use scp from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)